# Kafka connect jdbc not working in case of view

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In order to avoid the conversion of number column into byte, I have created a view of table in my source db, I have done the cast of column to numeric. Now ,while running the standalone connector, it is giving invalid number error. What can be the reason behind this?

> [2019-08-26 15:19:30,598] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table="SYSTEM"."V_DTD", query='null', topicPrefix='corpneft-test-', incrementingColumn='TRAN_ID', timestampColumns=[]}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask:332)
>           java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

```py
#
# Copyright 2018 Confluent Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Confluent Community License (the "License"); you may not use
# this file except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the
# License at
#
# http://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
# WARRANTIES OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
# specific language governing permissions and limitations under the License.
#

# A simple example that copies all tables from a SQLite database. The first few settings are
# required for all connectors: a name, the connector class to run, and the maximum number of
# tasks to create:
name=test-source-sqlite-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
# The remaining configs are specific to the JDBC source connector. In this example, we connect to a
# SQLite database stored in the file test.db, use and auto-incrementing column called 'id' to
# detect new rows as they are added, and output to topics prefixed with 'test-sqlite-jdbc-', e.g.
# a table called 'users' will be written to the topic 'test-sqlite-jdbc-users'.
connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:system/manager@10.101.142.25:3164/CBSPT
table.whitelist=V_DTD
table.types=VIEW
mode=incrementing
poll.interval.ms=10000
incrementing.column.name=TRAN_ID
topic.prefix=corpneft-test-
# Define when identifiers should be quoted in DDL and DML statements.
# The default is 'always' to maintain backward compatibility with prior versions.
# Set this to 'never' to avoid quoting fully-qualified or simple table and column names.
#quote.sql.identifiers=always
validate.non.null=false
#transformsTimestampConverter
#transforms.TimestampConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
#transforms.TimestampConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd
#transforms.TimestampConverter.target.type=string
```